# How can I change lxpanel digital clock font size?

Tags: fonts, gui, clock, lxpanel

I'd like to change the font size used to render the time in LXPanel's digital clock. I see the lxpanel config file has a font setting, but it appears to affect the window bars/button labels; I want something for just the clock.

Can the clock font size be changed? If so, how?

PS - I also tried changing the panel height (from 26 to 32), that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not possible without compiling it with necessary patch. There has been numerous forum threads and questions already about this topic already and it seems it's the only way (and I'm not sure it's possible).

Check these forum threads:

- http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=102341.0
- http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=213

and this is the configuration LXPanel supports now. http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel. You can change it to be bold, but you can't change the clock font individually for it. You must change the system font to achieve your desired font in Clock.

Comment: Aw man, that sucks. Thanks, though.